# Where can I watch "Attack on Titan" in Germany since it's not available on Crunchyroll?

Tags: attack-on-titan, resources

I will be honest, I am not a fan of Anime. But my daughter is.
I wanted to surprise her with Anime gift.
Long story short, we live in Germany. For a while she was mentioning a cool website where one can watch anime for a monthly subscription (in title). So after a while, I went and bought a premium membership. But it seems that most of the videos are not available in Germany.

This is the message I see (*Attack on Titan* case):

> Sorry, due to licensing limitations, videos are unavailable in your
> region: Attack on Titan

I read a bit, and this is really stupid. I expect for a payed membership to be able to watch a content.

What are my options?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I feel you. Copyright restrictions are stupid. They are complex and vary from country to country. The copyright owners apparently only licensed Crunchyroll to air this show in certain countries, Germany not one of them. Get a refund from Crunchyroll. And try Netflix. *Attack on Titan* is available on Netflix Germany.

**Caveat**

I think only the first season is available on Netflix Germany. DVD is another option worth looking into if your daughter wants to watch all the available episodes.

Comment: Do double check how much of the series is on Netflix though, the UK Netflix only has season 1 of 3.

Comment: @IG_42 You are right. That's a caveat. I think it is the same with Netflix Germany. I made the suggestion nonetheless because I couldn't think of any other legal channels in Germany to recommend to OP. There could be other options that I am not aware of, but I thought Netflix was a good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to use a VPN to change your IP address location to some other country where it is available.

You can use [VPN Gate](https://www.vpngate.net/en/) to get a free VPN service.

Answer (score 0):

There are sites like Funimation and AnimeLab to watch. Or try to change your VPN to check again to see if it is available on Crunchroll.